# .NET custom number formatting: what is the point of multiple digit placeholders (##)?

Tags: .net, number-formatting

In the C# documentation and in tutorials, people use examples like `##,#` `###,#`, `##,##`, etc. as a number format specifiers. Why would you use multiple `#` placeholders? It seems to do exactly the same thing as single `#` characters when used before the decimal separator, and no preceding `0` placeholder.

I.e.

- `####` == `#`
- `##,#` == `#,#`
- `###,#` == `#,#`
- `##,##` == `#,#`

Examples of docs using multiple superfluous `#`

- [Official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings): `2147483647 ("##,#", en-US)` -> `2,147,483,647`.

  - `#,#` does the same, right?
- [Tutorial](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/csharpnumerictostring_2.aspx): `Console.WriteLine(large.ToString("##.##"));`        // Outputs `"123456.79"`.

  - `#.##` does the same, right?
- [Tutorial](https://www.grapecity.com/componentone/docs/win/online-input/numericcustomformats.html): `format: ##### value: 123` output: `123`.

  - `#` does the same, right?

Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes. `##` is only used in examples meant to show it's *optional* and won't be filled if there's no digit. In the String.Format docs `2147483647 ("##,#", en-US)  is only used to illustrate the behavior of the grouping operator. The other examples use `#.###` or similar strings to show how decimal digits are specified

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm not sure what you mean. I know `#` means an optional digit (group). But `##,#` and `#,#` or `####` and `#` seem to have identical output. Why use the more verbose one, and/or why not explain somewhere they have identical output. Or, if do they not have identical output for certain inputs, could you give an example of such input?

See e.g. https://dotnetfiddle.net/PxhYsg

Answer (score 0):

The [# custom specifier documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#SpecifierD) states that it signifies you want to round input values to the nearest digit preceding a decimal:

> The "##" format string causes the value to be rounded to the nearest digit preceding the decimal, where rounding away from zero is always used. For example, formatting 34.5 with "##" would result in the value 35.

However, this appears to be misleading, at best. `##` on a value like `1234.56` will result in `1235`, as stated. However, a single `#` on the same value will *also* result in `12345`.

What *does* make a difference is the number of `#` placeholders *after* a decimal. For example, `#.#` on `1234.56` will result in `1234.6`, whereas `#.##` on the same value will result in `1234.56`.

I don't see how there would be a difference between `#` and `##` for comma declarations (`#,#`), unless maybe C# can detect your current culture when making the declaration itself. For me, in the US on an English language machine, my declaration has to be in English culture (I can't use `#,#` to indicate that I want to use decimal commas, even when specifying a region that uses decimal commas; I need to specify `#.#` and the region/culture, and C# will convert it).

Comment: Sure, `##` does that rounding. But `#` does that too. https://dotnetfiddle.net/CzJ0s9 . Am I missing a case where it does have different output between double and single `#`?

Comment: @J.H. Thinking about it more, it seems like the documentation is just incorrect. The behavior isn't actually specific to the nearest digit _preceding_ the decimal (in fact it doesn't make a difference on preceding digits at all in these examples, only on succeeding digits). I can also say that the _number_ of placeholders _after_ a decimal does change what place it is rounded to. For example, compare using `#.#` vs `#.##` on `value2` in your Fiddle.

Comment: @J.H. I rewrote the answer to reflect the information found during testing.

Comment: Thanks Tyler. (1) I agree, which is why I specified my question: "It seems to do exactly the same thing as single # characters *when used before the decimal separator*". I understand there's a difference in the amount of `#` after the decimal separator. (2) You seem to imply that `,` and `.` change function in a format string depending on the user culture. I don't think that's the case. `,` is _always_ the thousand separator and `.` _always_ the decimal separator character _in format strings_. Only in the output the user culture and thus their own separators are applied.

Comment: @J.H. I wasn't sure (see "unless maybe C# can detect")--I can't test both scenarios because I don't want to set my Windows OS and Visual Studio instance to a different culture to find out. In France (where they use `,` as a decimal), with French language versions of Windows (for example), do they still have to write `#.#` to indicate a decimal? Or can they write `#,#`?

Comment: @J.H. It may be a good idea to open a GitHub bug for that help article and request clarification on the documentation there, and reference this Stack Overflow question. In the past, I've done that and received explanations (or the help page has been updated/corrected).